# How to make two seperate clients share the same data from the server?

Tags: java, sockets

I have this server and client application that counts how many times a button has been clicked. Some other members here were kind enough to solve my previous issue with it, and now I have another.

When I start up the server, and a client connects, and the client clicks the button, the counter on the server side goes up. However, when a second client connects to the server, the counter resets to 0. I am thinking that the server creates a seperate instance of the counter for some reason.

Here is the (updated) server sided code:

```
public class Server {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Socket socket = null; //create a new socket
    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(9898);
    System.out.println("The server is running!");
    try {
        while (true) {
            new ClickServer(listener.accept()).start();
        }
    } finally {
        listener.close();
    }
}


/**
 * A private thread to handle clicking requests
 */
private static class ClickServer extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;
    AtomicInteger totalBets = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public void incrementTotalBets() {
        totalBets.incrementAndGet();

    }

    public int getTotalBets() {
        return totalBets.get(); 
    }



    public ClickServer(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        log("New connection with client at " + socket);
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);

                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String input = br.readLine();

                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

                if(input.equals("increment")) {

                    bw.write(String.valueOf(totalBets.incrementAndGet()));
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.flush();
                    System.out.println("Total Bets: " + getTotalBets());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log("Error handling client\n" + e);
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log("Error closing socket");
            }
            log("Connection with client closed");
        }
    }

    private void log(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
}
```

The `totalBets` integer is the counter. When multiple client join the server, and click the button, it should increment the counter and send it back based on what the counter already is. It shouldn't reset for every new client.

Here is the relevant client-sided code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
            String target = "";
            bw.write("increment" + "\n");
            bw.flush();
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String id = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("bet added: " + id);
            } catch (IOException e) {   
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

I'm not sure why a new instance of the Server is being created every time a new client connects. I did some debugging, and the server knows there is more than one client connected to the server at the same port.

Any help?

Thank you.

NOTE: the `ClickServer` class is nested inside the `Server` class. It just doesn't look that way in the code box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need a shared counter that's thread safe. I'd go for

```
  public static AtomicInteger totalBets = new AtomicInteger (0);
```

You'd have to change getter and setter some but this should share value between Clients. Or trash those methods and simply do

```
            if(input.equals("increment")) {
                bw.write(String.valueOf(totalBets.incrementAndGet ()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that, and they still don't share the value. The second client still starts from 0.

Comment: Could you share updated code? And totalBets has been made a static member variable?

Comment: I updated the server-sided code in the main post.

EDIT: Ohh! It wasn't static! Now it works! Thank you!

Comment: You need  static AtomicInteger totalBets = new AtomicInteger(0); // static to be shared between all instances of that class!

Comment: Thank you very much! Don't know how I missed that

Answer (score 0):

Try changing  :

```
public int totalBets = 0;
```

to:

```
public static int totalBets = 0;
```